# Why is my string doesn't accept null?

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

I need the String **receive the null value** if it is not found in mapper.getChave is what is returned. What I do? If I only get `nullPointerException`

```
for(String chave : linha.keySet()) {
                //Processa chave
                String novaChave = mapper.getChave(chave.trim());
                if (!(novaChave == null || novaChave.isEmpty())) {
                    //Processa valor
                    String novoValor = linha.getString(chave);
                    temp.append(novaChave, novoValor);
                }
                else {
                    extras.append(chave, linha.getString(chave));
                }

            }
```

Log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oknok.validacao.readers.PlanilhaReader.processaAtributosPlanilha(PlanilhaReader.java:237)
```

Line 237 is

```
String novaChave = mapper.getChave(chave.trim());
```

****UPDATE**: The first time the loop runs, i have a Nullpointer and `chave` contains a value

```
System.out.println(chave.isEmpty() + "\t" + chave + "\t" + chave.trim());
```

Output

```
false   Veículo Veículo
```

Comment: what is null - mapper or chave?

Comment: Is `mapper` initialized? What is the value of `chave` ?

Comment: Make sure `String` object is not null before you call it's methods. what is line number 237 in your code?

Comment: If you step through the code in your debugger you will be able to see which value is `null`  You should always assume a reference could be `null` unless you know for sure it shouldn't be e.g. because you accessed it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add null check for `mapper` as well as `chave`.

```
if (mapper!= null && chave != null && !"".equals(chave) {
    // do something
}
```

---

```
mapper.getChave(chave.trim())
       ^              ^   possible places for NPE.
```

Comment: Mapper is null, idk why. Is a Spring repository and in my code: `@Autowired Mapper mapper;`

Comment: Are you instantiating object of your class PlanilhaReader? i.e. doing `new PlanilhaReader()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: I was running jUnit unit test without the Spring annotations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably value of `chave` or `mapper` would be null and you are calling `trim()` and `.getChave()` on them respectively causing nullpointer

Comment: Value of `chave` isn't null or not empty and i have a nullPointerException

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais, then you can refer my answer.

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais then check the value of `mapper`.Try printing value of `mapper`

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais what is line number 237 in your code? best solution is try with `debuger`, you will  sort this out by your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether `chave` is null *before* trimming it or doing anything else (I'm assuming that `mapper` is pre-initialised and *not* null, but you should check that too)

e.g.

```
if (chave != null && !"".equals(chave.trim()) {
   // now do something
}
```

You may find it easier (more intuitive) to use something like Apache Commons `StringUtils.isNotBlank(String)`. See [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank(java.lang.String)) for the doc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a null string reference in `linha.keySet()`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow code change null string to "" : you can change "" to anything you like

```
String novaChave = mapper.getChave((chave == null ? "" : chave).trim());
```